# catch timeout event in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm setting a 10000 timeout on my backbone request. Is there a way to catch these events? I'm cathing a error event on my model then when I look at `response.status` it is always `0` I've googled the meaning of a status 0 and based on my initial search it means the request is interrupted. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at `response.statusText`, too, for a human-readable interpretation.

The `response` is an instance of the `jqXHR` object.  Lots of valuable info here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

If you're listening to the `error` event on your model, you should be able to filter based on the `status` and/or `statusText` to figure out what kind of error it was(e.g. Request Timeout vs. Bad Request vs. Not Found).

A list of error codes and their explanations are available here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Hope that helps!